# How to restrict API Key when calling the Reverse Geocoding API from Browser?

Tags: google-api, api-key, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using [Google Reverse Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#ReverseGeocoding) from **Browser**.

The API works fine when using **API Key with no restriction**.
For example: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API_KEY_WITH_NO_RESTRICTION&latlng=41.8857156,-87.64823779999999` - OK

But as I am calling the API from the **browser**, I would like to restrict the API Key, preferably request originating from certain domains.

Now, as per the [restriction](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#restriction) guideline, **HTTP Referer restrictions** won't work for the **Geocoding API** (one of the Google Web Service API). It returns error "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API." in such case!

The other option is to use **IP address restriction**. But it seems to be more suited if the call was originating from the server. In that case server address could be added in the restriction.

***How can I secure (restrict) the API Key if I want to continue to call the Geocoding API from the browser?***

Answer (score 5):

I figured out that I have to use [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) in order to be able to call the Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup) from **browser** (client) with **HTTP Referer restrictions** in place for the API Key.

In my initial implementation I used `fetch(requestUrl)` from the browser as it seemed very convenient and ended up with the above problem.

**Example (using TypeScript):**

1. Enable [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk)
2. Install required packages

```
npm install @googlemaps/js-api-loader
npm i -D @types/google.maps
```

3. `reverseGeo.ts`

```js
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const loadScript = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: API_KEY_WITH_REFERRER_RESTRICTION,
    version: 'weekly',
  });

  await loader.load();
};

export async function reverseGeo(
  lat: number, long: number
): Promise<string> {
  await loadScript();
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  const latlng = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: long,
  };

  try {
    const { results } = await geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng });
    if (results && results[0]) {
      return results[0].formatted_address;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle exception
  }

  throw new TypeError('Zero result or reverse geo Failed'); // or handle other way
}
```

4. `reverseGeo.spec.ts`

```
import { reverseGeo} from './reverseGeo';

it('should test reverseGeo', async () => {
  console.log(reverseGeo(22.5726, 88.3639));
});
```

Comment: THANKYOU. How did you figure this out? Based on everything I found, I thought I was hitting the client-side geocoding API... but apparently I wasn't.

Comment: Glad that it helped you. @DillonHarless

Comment: but how would you manage search queries. For example if you are using google map search in your application, how would human searched addresss will be converted to lat, long keeping the restriction intact

Comment: Do you know how I can use the google timezone api? Because i cannot find anywhere where to use this api with website restrictions because the example the included in their site fails https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview